# Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable everywhere on $(a,b)$ and has an integrable derivative, is f absolutely continuous?

Tags: bounded-variation, absolute-continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable everywhere on $(a,b)$ and have integrable derivative, is f absolutely continuous?

There is a theorem in Rudin that says this is true if f is differentiable on $[a,b]$, can we loosen this to differentiable on $(a,b)$?

Comment: $(a,b)=\bigcup_n[a+2^{-n},b-2^{-n}]$.

Comment: @QiyuWen Since the function is AC on each interval, it is AC on the union? I am pretty sure that is not true. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056309/does-absolute-continuity-of-f-on-epsilon-1-and-continuity-at-f-0-imply

Comment: You're right, I was busy with other things and did not give much thought. Now that I have time: since $f$ is not required to be continuous at $a$ or $b$, of course there's no reason for it to be AC on $[a,b]$. So let's suppose that $f\in C[a,b]$. Then $f(x)=\int_a^xf'\,dm$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, which proves $f$ to be AC on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @QiyuWen How do you justify that $f$ is in the integral form? That is basically assuming it is AC.

Comment: Because $\int_a^xf'\,dm\to\int_a^bf'\,dm$ as $x\to b$.

Comment: @QiyuWen I think I understand now. So we know that $f(x)-f(a)=\int_{a}^{x}f'$ for all $x<b$.  Now by continuity of $f$, $x \to b$ we get $f(b)-f(a)=\int_{a}^{b}f'$ correct? we can move the limit inside the integral as $f'$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ by just defining it as $0$ on the endpoints.